# How to DRY media queries

Tags: css

I have two media queries that have exactly the same .css properties:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) { 
   h2 {
        font-size: 3rem;
        line-height: 3.5rem;
    }
    .slider h3 {
        font-size: 2.5rem;
        line-height: 2.5rem;
    }
    .col .wrapper {
      padding: 3rem;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) { 
   h2 {
        font-size: 3rem;
        line-height: 3.5rem;
    }
    .slider h3 {
        font-size: 2.5rem;
        line-height: 2.5rem;
    }
    .col .wrapper {
      padding: 3rem;
    }
}
```

What do I have to do to DRY them? I tried:

`@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px)`

and didn't work. Also tried:

`@media only screen and (max-width: 320px), (max-width: 480px)`

and didn't work either. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: `(max-width: 320px), (max-width: 320px)` , chaining two same max-width values?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to change the values.

Comment: also usually in CSS media queries, the logical operator `and` goes something like `max-width` and `min-width` and not on two max-widths (as you have tried doing). It makes no sense.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since they both contain exactly the same CSS Declarations, what's the point of having both of them?

Just get rid of the `@media only screen and (max-width: 320px){...}` and you should be fine.

The remaining `@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){...}` declarations will automatically be applied to all widths up-to 480px (this includes 320px, since 320px < 480px).

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the latter since they are just the same css and the media query `(max-width: 480px)` still hits resolutions `320px` and below

So you only need this :

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) { 
   h2 {
        font-size: 3rem;
        line-height: 3.5rem;
    }
    .slider h3 {
        font-size: 2.5rem;
        line-height: 2.5rem;
    }
    .col .wrapper {
      padding: 3rem;
    }
}
```